# Getting TCP socket statistics with Python?

Tags: python, sockets

Is there a way to use Python's `socket` module to replicate some of the functionality of the Linux [ss](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ss) utility?

> `ss` is used to dump socket statistics. It allows showing information similar to `netstat`. It can display more TCP and state informations than other tools.

Pretty much all of the `socket` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) revolves around creating new sockets, but I can't find any information on getting statistics from the system's sockets.

Comment: Why? What use is it in an applicaion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how such functionality could be implemented purely with the `socket` module. The `socket` module is for working directly with sockets: opening/closing, sending/receiving, etc. It's simply a thin wrapper over the standard BSD socket interface.

On the other hand, getting metadata about existing sockets already allocated on the system requires knowledge of the other processes running on a system. This has little to do with actually manipulating a socket, and much more to do with monitoring other processes and/or their file descriptors.

For example, it seems that both `ss` and `netstat` are actually implemented (at least on Linux) by reading and parsing the `/proc` pseudo-filesystem. (See [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/net-tools/code/ci/master/tree/lib/pathnames.h) and [here](https://github.com/sivasankariit/iproute2/blob/master/misc/ss.c#L184), for examples.) The kernel manages the processes and their opened sockets, and exposes (some of) the information about them to other processes via `procfs`. This provides a simple and safe way of exporting some of the information about processes to userspace, obviating the need for lots of system calls or reading kernel data structures directly.

Note that it pretty much *has* to work this way. Strong process isolation necessitates that information about another process's open files, including sockets, has to come through the kernel in some way. That could be either via `procfs` on Linux, or some kernel-provided API (e.g. `libproc` on macOS). Anything else would be a massive security hole.

As an alternative to the `socket` module, you could try the `psutil` package or something similar. The [`psutil.net_connections()`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/release-3.0.1/index.html?highlight=open%20files#psutil.net_connections) function seems appropriate.

Comment: Thanks so much for the details explanation and suggestion to look into `psutil`! That looks like it'll do the trick perfectly.